# How to cleanup fireEvents after each test in react-testing-library?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I've noticed that if you run any sort of `fireEvent` in a react-testing-library test, it isn't cleaned up after the test by `afterEach(cleanup)`.

For example, the following test will pass for both tests, **even though they are both expecting completely different things but are identical in every way**.

```
afterEach(cleanup);

describe("<ToggleIconButton>", () => {

  // TEST 1
  it("shows the <VisibileIcon> svg icon on click", () => {
    const { container } = render(<ToggleIconButton />);
    const button = container.querySelector("button");
    fireEvent.click(button);
    const svg = container.querySelector("svg");
    expect(svg.getAttribute("data-testid")).toBe("visibleIcon");
  });

  // TEST 2
  it("shows the <NotVisibleIcon> svg icon on double-click", () => {
    const { container } = render(<ToggleIconButton />);
    const button = container.querySelector("button");
    fireEvent.click(button);
    const svg = container.querySelector("svg");
    expect(svg.getAttribute("data-testid")).toBe("notVisibileIcon");
  });

});
```

The reason for this is because the `fireEvent.click(button)` in `TEST 1` carries over into `TEST 2`, so when the `fireEvent.click(button)` is called in `TEST 2`, it acts like it was a double-click.

How do I ensure that the fireEvent's are cleaned up after each test?

Comment: This seems unlikely. Tests are supposed to be isolated. The two `button`s are separate instances. Have you tried to run each test separately to make sure they fail?

Comment: Same result if I run both tests separately. They work fine if I put the tests in separate files though. And I actually managed to get it to work by simply moving the `const svg = ...` above `const button = ...`, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I don't know how your component works so I can't say if it makes sense or not. Just so you know calling `fireEvent.click` twice won't simulate a double click. You have to use `fireEvent.dblClick`.